# Propagation of uncertainty (intersection of two graphs)

Tags: regression, error-propagation

The situation is as follows:

- I performed necessary measurements and used them to create two graphs.
- I used polynomial regression to find the point of intersection.

What I know:

- precision of instruments (absolute error of X and Y values of the points belonging to the graphs).
- polynomial regression equations and coefficients of determination.

What I need to find out:

- uncertainty of X and Y values of the intersection point.

In case something sounds unclear (English obviously isn't my native language) - I basically need to do something similar to [this](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/07/04/Estimating-where-two-functions-intersect-using-data/) (but with polynomial regression)

The question is: what methods should be used to accomplish it?

Comment: Perhaps the material at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15511 will give you a start.