# Intersecting a linear and exponential with uncertain parameterisations

Tags: time-series, forecasting, monte-carlo

I'm trying to forecast the point at which two trends will intersect. One is exponential, the other decreasing and linear.

In particular, I want to do this with a distribution over the parameters of each (see Figure below), and then get the resulting distribution over coordinates of intersection.

[image: Figure 1]

I am an amateur in probabilistic programming languages, so am looking for a more detailed answer than e.g. "try pymc".

Comment: The methods used to solve the analogous problem (for the intersection of two lines) apply *mutatis mutandis* to this one: see the solution at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15511/estimating-the-intersection-of-two-lines/15512#15512.

Comment: @Jacob Are these done on independent sets of data, or related data?

Comment: @Glen_b I'm not fitting the lines to data. I am generating the parameters by reasonable guesses.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make this clear in the question. If the fits are guesses, where do the intervals come from?

Comment: @Glen_b I don't see how that affects the answer. I can guess a parameter distribution (e.g. normal for convenience), parameterize based on historical data, and add some uncertainty.

Comment: "add some uncertainty" gives no basis for a probability model on which to base distributional inference. i.e. I think it matters, and in my opinion your question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: I don't follow. What if I had said "use the historical mean as the mean, then assume a normal and choose a suitable standard deviation"? Regardless, the question concerns what happens *after* that, when I already have two normals over the slope and exponent of the two lines.