# R: Finding average point and SD of intersection for multiple lines

Tags: r, least-squares, linear

I have a set of ~87 lines that are described by linear equations (y=ax+b). (These lines are fitted from OLS regression). I want to find the average point of intersection for the lines and (since there is no single point) the standard deviation of this point. So far I have used a brute-force approach: calculate all pairwise intersection points and calculate the mean. I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: Could you please describe the data used to fit the lines?  In particular, to what extent are any data shared among the 87 separate fits and are the fits made separately or all together in one procedure?  Could you tell us what the underlying application is? FWIW, a solution for just *two* lines based on independent datasets is described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15511.

Comment: The lines are fit to scaling relationships between two body parts (for example leg length versus head width). Each line is fit to measures from multiple (~50) individuals in the same population, and there are 87 populations. I want to know, where, on average, the lines intersect. No data are shared between the 87 separate fits. It would be great to have an estimate of the CI around the average intercept point also. I have done this by bootstrapping (I.e. resampling the data and recalculating the mean point of intersection for the resampled lines) but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.